# MySQL select by primary key against 100M of records within 30ms

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, myisam

I have no expirience with MySQL and database performance tuning in general.

Wondering whether it is possible to perform a large number of selects against 100 millions of records by primary key within 30ms per request in average.

**Some details:**

- PK is 16 bytes.
- Each record is approximately 100 bytes and can be shrinked to 24 bytes if normalized (though cardinality is approximately 10 to 1 and we need joins in this case).
- Table should be writeable. There may be 1 update per 1 select, though updates can be deferred and their performance is less critical.
- I could allocate up to 8GB for mysql needs.
- Disk is a regular HDD (this concerns me the most, because seek time is about 9ms)

Please, suggest, what storage engine is preferable, what mysql parameters should be tuned.
Also suggest, please, some technics (perhaps selecting groups of records with where in() against record by record, etc.) to improve performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would be better posted on [dba.se]

Comment: worse case estimate when looking for an PRIMARY KEY index |log(10000000)/log(1024/3*2/(16+4)) + 1| =  6 disk seeks  around 54ms needed seek time if indexes are not in memory... you really should use innodb and warmup the innodb buffer bool this way  table data and indexes can be fetched from the memory.. and this is indeed an better question for Database Administrators

Comment: My bad, dataset is actually 100M records. 10 millions would fit into RAM. I've put my question to dba.stackexchange, though leaving this one here. Raymond, why do you think InnoDb would be a better choice?